# Method to create a model instance based on a request object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-managers

I have a model like this:

```
class UserSubmission(models.Model):
    mantra = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=15) # xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

I want to create a function like so:

```
def create_submission(request, mantra):
    s = UserSubmission(mantra=mantra)
    ip_meta_entry = 'HTTP_X_REAL_IP' in request.META and 'HTTP_X_REAL_IP' or 'REMOTE_ADDR'
    s.ip = request.META[ip_meta_entry]
    s.save()
    return s
```

**Note:** The above is purely for demonstration purposes and not *exactly* what I'm doing but I digress...

Where would be the ideal place to put a function like so? Class method on the model? In the manager? What would be best practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to put functions that use `request` in views.py.  Aside from error checking, your code should work fine.

```
def create_submission(request, mantra):
    ip_meta_entry = 'HTTP_X_REAL_IP' in request.META and 'HTTP_X_REAL_IP' or 'REMOTE_ADDR'
    s = UserSubmission(
        mantra=mantra,
        ip=request.META[ip_meta_entry])
    s.save()
    return s
```